# Referencing static files above parent directory in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask and I have around 6 web apps in my repository and so I am trying to pull out all the mutually used .css and .js files into a library directory so my directory structure looks like this:

```
lib/
  static/
    css/
      my-css.css
    js/
    images/
      my-image.jpg
webapps/
  webapp_1/
    src/
      webapp_1/
        main.py
        templates/
          base.html
          main.html
          other.html
  webapp_2/
    same as webapp_1 more or less
  .
  .
  .
  etc
```

So from base.html I need to reference the static directory in some form like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../../../../../lib/static/css/my-css.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../lib/static/images/my-image.jpg">
```

And this works when I have a plain HTML file but not when I use it as a template through Flask. Is there something I need to change or some way I can use these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../static')
```

Then in your templates:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/css/my-css.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/images/my-image.jpg">
```

Comment: one other question, can I keep my static files in more than one folder? I have some that are specific to each webapp and most are relevant to all of them so I want to different folders

Comment: @clifgray You'll do best with one *root* static directory, but you could easily have each site maintain its own root and alias/symlink in the shared static files under, say /static/common